# Here is the code for the PHPMailer and ImprovMX

Tags: phpmailer

Below is the code for the PHPMailer and ImprovMX. I have tried to use this code below so I can connect to ImprovMX and us a mail forward. The mx record was updated successfully but still it don't send via mail forward. I am using infinityfree hosting and they said this is not an issuse as you can use PHPMailer because they don't allow mail forwarding on free hosting.`enter code here`

```
<?php
$result = "";
if(isset($_POST['send'])){
    require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    //$mail->isSMTP();
    //$mail->Host = 'smtp.yandex.com';
    //$mail->Port = 465;
    //$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    //$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
    //personal info

    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $body = $_POST['message'];
    //end of input info

    $mail->setFrom('info@domain.cf');

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $email . "<br>" . $phone . "<br>" . 
    $body;

    if(!$mail->send()){
        $result = 'Message not sent. Please try again';
    }else{
        $result = 'Message sent. We will respond to you as soon as possible';
    }
    header("Location:index.php"); 
}
    
?>
```

Comment: You're using a very old version of PHPMailer, so update. You have no error reporting and have not included any of the SMTP debug output, though you won't be getting any because you have disabled SMTP. I'd recommend starting again with one of the examples provided with PHPMailer, and read the troubleshooting guide before asking questions that there are known answers to – it will save both you and us a lot of time and effort.